# Did the current US administration express a position about national emergency state extension?

Tags: united-states, state-of-emergency

*Note: this is related to [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/15415/why-is-the-us-still-in-a-state-of-emergency)*

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_of_emergency), the US is in a national emergency state for a long period (more than 15 years):

> **The United States declared a national emergency on September 14, 2001** in response to the September 11, 2001 attacks that remains in effect. This emergency proclamation suspends certain provisions of law that limit the size of the military and the duration of military service. Former Presidents George W. Bush and Barack Obama, and current President Donald Trump, have chosen to extend the duration of the proclamation each year following its original declaration. Currently, **the proclamation will remain in effect until September 14, 2018, unless it is extended again by President Trump.**

<sup>(**emphasis added**)</sup>

From a layman perspective, a state of emergency sounds like an extraordinary measure that span over months, years at most. Yet the US has been experiencing it for more than a decade.

**Question:** Did the current US administration express a position on the national emergency state extension?

Comment: According to https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/politics/2017/09/14/permanent-emergency-trump-becomes-third-president-renew-extraordinary-post-9-11-powers/661966001/, we are actually in at least 30 states of emergency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The president, through executive orders, does express conclusions justifying extension of existing state(s) of emergency.   But there are such emergencies still being extended that started earlier than 2001.

**Oldest state of emergency.**  A state of emergency relating to Iran, [first signed in **1995** by Bill Clinton](https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/sanctions/Documents/12957.pdf), was [extended by Donald Trump on March 12, 2018.](https://www.whitehouse.gov/presidential-actions/notice-regarding-continuation-national-emergency-respect-iran-2/), after this question was asked.   ***So yes, states of emergency can last for decades.***  The specific "position" expressed in that extension was:

> Actions and policies of the Government of Iran, including its development of ballistic missiles, support for international terrorism, and human rights abuses continue to pose an unusual and extraordinary threat to the national security, foreign policy, and economy of the United States.

The specific emergency powers invoked are not listed in the extension, but a long history of previous executive orders are, starting with the 1995 one.

**9/11 related state of emergency.**   The [2001 state of emergency](https://www.state.gov/j/ct/rls/other/des/122570.htm) you seem more interested in seems also to have been [most recently extended on September 18, 2018.](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefings-statements/text-notice-continuation-national-emergency-respect-persons-commit-threaten-commit-support-terrorism/)   The expressed reasoning was:

> The actions of persons who commit, threaten to commit, or support terrorism continue to pose an unusual and extraordinary threat to the national security, foreign policy, and economy of the United States. For this reason, the national emergency declared in Executive Order 13224 of September 23, 2001, and the measures adopted on that date to deal with that emergency, must continue in effect beyond September 23, 2018. Therefore, in accordance with section 202(d) of the National Emergencies Act (50 U.S.C. 1622(d)), I am continuing for 1 year the national emergency with respect to persons who commit, threaten to commit, or support terrorism declared in Executive Order 13224.

P.S.  The state of Israel seems to have been operating under a continuous state of emergency since 1946.